# error: No module named registration,having installed the registration module

Tags: django

I installed the registration module. When I tried to run syncdb (% python manage.py syncdb),it gives me `ImportError: No module named registration`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'registration',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rango',
)


wjl@wjl-Lenovo-Product:~/文档/djcode/tango_with_django_project$ python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named registration
```

Comment: How did you install the module?

Comment: Using pip:

pip install django-registration-redux

Comment: what is the output on doing `pip freeze`? does it show the registration module?

Comment: Thanks,I  installed incorrectly.Now Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_registration_redux-1.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for django-registration-redux==1.2
Finished processing dependencies for django-registration-redux==1.2

Comment: However,when I run syncdb (% python manage.py syncdb),it gives OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_registration_redux-1.2-py2.7.egg/registration/migrations'

Comment: In my case. I uninstall and install django-registration-redux again, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `registration` module path to `sys.path` if it is not there.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/registration/module')
```

Answer (score 0):

easy_install -Z django-registration

Running this in cmd solved the same problem with me.